# How to compare a sample against some baseline data?

Tags: distributions, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

First let me describe the situation I'm dealing with:

I'm looking at performance data for a software system. I have data for many versions of the software, including ongoing. For each version I have a series of values for the run-times of tests run against it, usually about 20 (of the same test). These generally look normally distributed (for each version).

What I want to know is, given some data for runs against a new version, is the new distribution *different* in a way that merits investigation. The comparison could be either against the previous version, or against a set of previous versions that have been selected as a having "stable" performance: a kind of baseline. Any kind of change could be relevant: a change in the mean, variance or shape could be significant.

Now, the different versions are, well, different, but for those in the baseline I think I can assume that they're effectively samples from the same distribution. So I've got $X_1, ... X_n, X'$, for $n \geq 1$, and I want to test whether $X'$ is relevantly similar to the $X_i$s in an automated fashion.

From what I've seen on the internet I've come up with a few options:

a) Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: either of $X'$ vs $X_n$, or of $X'$ vs $\bigcup X_i$.

b) T-test: similarly.

c) Mann-Whitney/Wilcoxon test?

Firstly, I'm not clear which would be better for my situation, as they both test for different kinds of "similarity", or whether I should use both and report some combination of the results.

Secondly, looking at the data, it looks like the $X_i$, while normally distributed, tend to move around a bit: so their means vary, but e.g. the variance is similar. If I just lump them into one big sample, then this information is lost; for example, it will look like the typical variance is much bigger than it actually is. For that reason I wondered whether I might be able to instead look at the distribution of the means and variances of the $X_i$s, and compare the mean and variance of $X'$ against that, somehow.

However, I'm unsure how to do that: I think the means should follow a t-distribution, so I ought to be able to estimate the probability of getting $\bar{X'}$ given that the sample came from the same distribution, but that's the wrong conditional probability! (although that's kind of just what a p-value is...) I can't do a proper t-test as that requires either more than one value to compare against, or the assumption that the variance is shared, which I'm not sure I have.

Finally, my inner Bayesian feels like I ought to be able to do better than producing p-values for rejecting the null hypotheses: surely I ought to be able to calculate a posterior probability that $X'$ is, say, drawn from the same distribution as the $X_i$s?

Apologies for the huge question; I hope this gives a reasonable idea of where I'm coming from! I'm mathematically trained, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with statistics, so I can cope with some maths.

Edit: I'm also familiar with R; I'm going to be using it to do the calculations... once I figure out what to calculate!

Comment: Are you still interested in this question? I think I might have some suggestions.

Comment: Absolutely! That would be very helpful.

Comment: To clarify, there is only one kind of test that you are considering here, right? The $X_i$'s are vectors with the test values for version $i$ in them, right?

Comment: Also, there is sort of normal variation between versions, which you don't want to detect? You just want to detect variation that's beyond the normal version to version variance?

Comment: The Xis are vectors with the test values for version i, yes. Can't say much about them; that's kind of the problem! Part of the problem is that I'm not sure what I'm looking for: the KS test seems to do a decent job of picking out things that look "different" so far. I'm looking for a difference in shape, or in location, basically.

Answer (score 1):

I normally have a Bayesian bias, but If I understand you correctly, I think Frequentist hypothesis testing is fairly appropriate here.

I think you probably want to do a t-test with of each $X_i$ with $X'$. This will tell you whether the mean of a given version is significantly different than the mean of the baseline.

You can then also do a [F-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances), which tests if the variances are different.

You may also consider computing Bayesian credible interval for the difference of means and seeing if 0 is outside that. Check out [Bolstad's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470141158) Chapter 12. There's probably also a credible interval for the ratio of variances.

With more sophisticated Bayesian approaches you could probably sqeeze a tiny bit more information out of data, but I think you're probably much better off doing this and collecting more data if you need it.

I don't think you want to pool the $X_i$'s because that will tell you whether the sample weighted mean of version tests is different than $X'$. If I understand you, this is not what you're interested in, you're interested in *which* versions are different.

If you're interested in which versions go beyond the normal variation between versions, then you'll have to do something more complex.